# running a for loop in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I would like to know whats the best way to accomplish this:

I have a file with below data:

```
server1   
chl(abc.123) chltype(RCVR)
chl(xyz.123) chltype(RCVR)
server2
chl(abc.000) chltype(RCVR)
chl(abc.999) chltype(RCVR)
chl(xyz.456) chltype(RCVR)
```

Now I want to run a script which does this.,

ssh to server 1 and run the following commands for those listed under server 1 , then ssh to server 2 and run the commands for those listed under server2

for example, on server 1

```
echo chl(abc.123) chltype(RCVR)
```

Comment: I have removed the blank lines in between, let me know if the blank lines should be there..

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ ${line} =~ ^server\d+$ ]] ; then
        server=${line}
        continue
    fi
    ssh ${server} "echo ${line}"
done
```

Assuming the format of your file doesn't change.

Comment: I suspect `serverN` in his example are just placeholders, the server names don't actually begin with `server`.

Comment: @Barmar - I figured that but I was assuming the server names matched a pattern of some sort. I'll change it to word count perhaps

Comment: It looks more like the server lines have one token, the data lines have more than one.